# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I can's seem to figure out why I'm getting this error.

I need to turn `user_link` part into hyperlink(right now it outputs a text on the frontend). Error happens on this line in my shortcode.php file. I guess there is an error with `a href` part:

```
$output .= '<td>' . $order->billing_first_name . ' ' . $order->billing_last_name . ' <a href='" . $order->user_link . "'>" . $order['user_link'] . "</a> </td>';
```

Comment: Easy, see the colors where it go's wrong. You should use an IDE.

Comment: try this:
`$output .= '<td>' . $order->billing_first_name . ' ' . $order->billing_last_name . ' <a href="' . $order->user_link . '">' . $order['user_link'] . '</a> </td>';`
and after try to change your editor...

Comment: A syntax error should be easy to track, look at the error message and it should tell you at what column the problem starts. As  Xorifelse mentioned, the color highlighting done by StackOverflow itself tells you that the problem is somewhere in here `' <a href='" . $order->user_link . "'>" . $order['user_link']` Look for mismatched quotes and where the string should end but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is right here:

```
. ' <a href='" .
```

Notice how you're starting with a single quote and ending with a double.

Definitely consider using an IDE.  It will make these easy bugs blatantly obvious.  I highly recommend PHPStorm, or if you don't want to spend anything, sublime text (Not an IDE but will provide linting and highlighting).

On top of that I'd recommend using some type of templating engine eventually.  You should always try to avoid writing HTML as strings.

Comment: Even notepad++ will highlight syntax problems

Answer (score 1):

```
$output .= '<td>' . $order->billing_first_name . ' ' . $order->billing_last_name . ' <a href="' . $order->user_link . '">' . $order['user_link'] . '</a> </td>';
```

You switched the ' and " in the a href. I also changed the two " to ' in the a description.